# How to access window.crypto from a chrome extention script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cryptography

I want to create a small extension which allows for certificate based authentication. I wanted to handle the certificate in a background script, but I can't find a way to access window.crypto from there. Can I access it from there and if not where is to best place to handle the certificates?

Comment: It can be used in the background script just the same so the question is unanswerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve). Note that `window` is not needed and is not present in a ManifestV3 service worker so just use `crypto` or `self.crypto`.

Comment: That allready is the answer thanks. I simply didn't know that I have to omit `window`.